# 1 insert or save button for 2 or more databases

Tags: database, vb.net

I'm creating a system which is a database management system. i have four (and counting) databases here, but i'm wondering that is it possible to use just 1 insert or save button for 2 or more databases?

I'm new at vb.net.

Below is my code for my insert or save button. And i can't go any further because i'm thinking if there is any possibilities to use just 1 insert or save button for many databases.

```
Private Sub btnSaveOPR_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSaveOPR.Click
        provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
        'Change the following to your access database location
        dataFile = "C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\ODRNEWSYSTEM\ODRNEWSYSTEM\Database1.accdb"
        connString = provider & dataFile
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim str As String
        str = "insert into OPR ([OPROffice], [ID], [Elements], [Objectives], [Measures],[Baseline_as_of_2013],[Target_by_2016],[Actual_Accomplishments_2014],[Actual_Accomplishments_2015],[Actual_Accomplishments_2016],[Initiatives]) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("OPROffice", CType(OPROfficeTextBox.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("ID", CType(IDTextBox.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Elements", CType(ElementsTextBox.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Objectives", CType(ObjectivesTextBox.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Measures", CType(MeasuresTextBox.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Baseline_as_of_2013", CType(Baseline_as_of_2013TextBox.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Target_by_2016", CType(Target_by_2016TextBox.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Actual_Accomplishments_2014", CType(Actual_Accomplishments_2014TextBox.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Actual_Accomplishments_2015", CType(Actual_Accomplishments_2015TextBox.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Actual_Accomplishments_2016", CType(Actual_Accomplishments_2016TextBox.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Initiatives", CType(InitiativesTextBox.Text, String)))
        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            myConnection.Close()
            Me.Validate()
            Me.OPRBindingSource.EndEdit()
            Me.OPRTableAdapter.Update(Me.Database1DataSet.OPR)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        RefreshData()
        OPRDataGridView.RefreshEdit()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Your search button inserts a new record?

Comment: @Blorgbeard oops sorry bro. i asked the wrong question, wait i'll edit it

Comment: Put all of this in a new method with arguments you can pass to determine what database to hit. Thats one option as how are you going to know which one to hit... For example I have a connection manager class that I use to hit more than a few databases.

Comment: Bottom line - you need to execute SQL for each DB connection. But, I think, there is something wrong with your general design if you have to do this. You probably could do this through one DB and within DB you would have replication jobs/mechanisms.